# Splitting and rebuilding file in nodejs changes its length with some formats

Tags: node.js, file, buffer, chunks

I am writing a script to split files into chunks and rebuild these files from chunks.

This works fine for `.txt` files and `.js` files

However, when I try my script with more "complex" files such as images `.png`, `.pdf` or `.docx`, the file is not correctly rebuilt.

For example, with an image that is originally `2 057 bytes` long, I retrieve a `3 387 bytes` long file that cannot be read by anything.

I don't know how to debug this. So I would appreciate someone to point out what is wrong or how to find hat is wrong with my work.

Here is my script so far:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileName = "sample.png";
var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
var bufferLength = fileBuffer.length;
var chunkSize = 10;
var chunkQtt = bufferLength / chunkSize;
var result = splitBuffer(fileBuffer, chunkSize);

result.forEach(writeFileFromBuf);
var resFromChunk = [];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    resFromChunk.push(fs.readFileSync('./chunks/fileChunk' + i));
}


fs.createWriteStream("rebuilt_" + fileName).write(Buffer.concat(resFromChunk).toString());

console.log("quantity of chunks: " + chunkQtt);
console.log("buffer length " + bufferLength);
console.log("chunks size " + chunkSize);

function splitBuffer(buffer, csize) {
    let pointer = 0;
    var result = [];
    var currentSize = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < chunkQtt; i++) {
        result[i] = buffer.slice(pointer, pointer + csize);
        console.log("length " + result[i].length + " data: " + result[i].toString());
        currentSize += result[i].length;
        pointer += csize;
    }
    console.log("retrieved size " + currentSize)
    return result
}

function writeFileFromBuf(element, index, array) {
    var fileName = "./chunks/fileChunk" + index;
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, element);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine until you get to the point where you try to glue all of the read-in chunks together and write the result out into the reassembled file "rebuilt_sample.png".  All of the steps prior to that point (reading the original file, breaking it into chunks, writing out the chunks into individual files, reading the chunk files back in) handle the file data as buffers containing bytes that have not been examined or interpreted in any way.

But then this happens:

```
fs.createWriteStream("rebuilt_" + fileName).write(Buffer.concat(resFromChunk).toString());
```

In that statement, the `toString()` call causes the bytes in the concatenated buffer to be interpreted (or "decoded") as characters, and then during the `write()` operation those characters are converted (or "encoded") back into a byte stream which gets written into the file.  The decoding and encoding activities are carried out according to the rules of your program's locale, which is probably a UTF-8 locale.  UTF-8 is a method for translating Unicode characters into, and from, a sequence of bytes.

That's fine **IF** the bytes in the buffer can all be successfully decoded as characters by the rules of UTF-8.  That's very likely to be the case when the input file is a text file such as a `.txt` or `.js` file.  But when the file is a non-text file (often called a "binary" file), it's likely that some of the byte sequences in the file will not be legitimate UTF-8 byte sequences and therefore those bytes will not be translatable into characters.  This will happen for almost all bytes whose value is greater than 127 decimal, 0x7F hexadecimal.  Your `sample.png` is one of these binary files that contains some bytes that can not be translated into characters.

There are several ways that a program might react to untranslatable bytes.  For example, it might crash, it might silently skip those bytes, it might skip them and emit an error report, it might stop translating after seeing a bad byte, it might produce a completely empty string.  In this case Node silently converts each illegal byte into a Unicode Replacement Character "�" in the generated string.  Then when that string is encoded back into bytes during the `write()` operation, each of those Replacement Characters is converted according the UTF-8 rules and becomes the three-byte sequence `0xEF 0xBF 0xFD` in the rebuilt file.

This is why your rebuilt file is bigger than the original file.  Almost every byte in the original file whose value was greater than 0x7F is replaced by three bytes in the rebuilt file.

The fix for this problem is easy.  Simply get rid of the `.toString()` call in that line and let your program treat the concatenated buffer as an uninterpreted collection of bytes:

```
fs.createWriteStream("rebuilt_" + fileName).write(Buffer.concat(resFromChunk))
```

Comment: Wow, very nice answer.